# Using include to import all the urls from my django app

Tags: django, django-views

I'm learning Django and I think I'm following an old tutorial. What I'm trying to do right now is connect using the `urls.py`(in main app) all the urls from my other app.

First of all, import the library `include` (and the others that where already).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
```

The write the url/path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Platform_App', include('Platform_App/urls.py', namespace = 'Platform_App', app_name = 'Platform_App')),
]
```

But reading the [django information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path), I tried to do something like this that doesn't work,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Platform_App', include('Platform_App.urls')),
]
```

How I have to do it correctly? Thank very much!!!

Comment: Which error you are facing now?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to set URL as below...

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('Platform_App/', include('<project_name>.<app_name>.<urls>')),
]
```

In your case...

```
urlpatterns = [    
    path('Platform_App/', include('<project_name>. Platform_App.urls')),
]
```